# process_not_owner_of_odbc_connection :ODBC connection

Tags: erlang, odbc, elixir

Has anyone ran across this error when querying with erlang odbc:

> {:error, :process_not_owner_of_odbc_connection}

I am writing a connection pool and the :ODBC.connect('conn string) is ran inside the genserver and the returned pid is put into the state... But when i get that PID back out of the gen server, I get the above error when trying to run an :odbc.param_query with that pid... How are we suppose to create a connection pool if we can use pids created in a genserver?

Anyone have any ideas?

GenServer:

```
defmodule ItemonboardingApi.ConnectionPoolWorker do
    use GenServer

    def start_link([]) do
      IO.puts "Starting Connection Pool"
      GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, [])
    end

    def init(_) do
        :odbc.start
      {ok, pid} = :odbc.connect('DSN=;UID=;PWD=', [])
      IO.inspect pid
      {:ok, pid}
    end

    def handle_call(:get_connection, _from, state) do
      IO.puts "Inspecting State:"
      IO.inspect state
      IO.puts("process #{inspect(self())} getting odbc connection")
      {:reply, state, state}
    end
  end
```

Calling Function:

```
def get_standards_like(standard) do
    :poolboy.transaction(
      :connection_pool,
      fn pid -> 
       connection = GenServer.call(pid, :get_connection) 
       IO.inspect connection

      val =
        String.upcase(standard)
        |> to_char_list

      # Call Stored Proc Statement
      spstmt = '{call invlibr.usp_vm_getStandards (?)}'

      case :odbc.param_query(connection, spstmt, [
             {{:sql_char, 50}, [val]}
           ])
           |> map_to_type(ItemonboardingCore.Standard) 
           do
        {:ok, mapped} ->
          {:ok, mapped}

        {:updated, affected_count} ->
          {:ok, affected_count}

        {:executed, o, a} ->
          {:ok, o, a}

        {:error, _} ->
          {:bad}
      end 
     end
    )
  end
```

I have confirmed that the pids in the genserver are infect the correct odbc pids and the GenServer.Call returns one of them.

****EDIT****
Here is what I did to fix the issue. I didnt know that the process that created the connection, had to be the process that runs the query. A slight change to my worker to pass the query into has fixed my issue.  This is a rough first pass, a few things still need to be done to the worker.

```
defmodule ItemonboardingApi.ConnectionPoolWorker do
    use GenServer

    def start_link([]) do
      IO.puts "Starting Connection Pool"
      GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, [])
    end

    def init(_) do
      :odbc.start(:app)
      {ok, pid} = :odbc.connect('DSN=;UID=;PWD=', [])
      IO.inspect pid
      {:ok, pid}
    end

    def handle_call(:get_connection, _from, state) do
      {:reply, state, state}
    end

    def handle_call({:query, %{statement: statement, params: params}}, _from, state) do
      #TODO Check if pid is alive and start if needed.
      {:reply, :odbc.param_query(state, to_charlist(statement), params),  state}
    end
  end
```

Comment: you'll also need to update the state if the connection changes to new connection or null if you can't establish one. That's similar to what I do.

Comment: @RomanRabinovich Do you have an example?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's going to be a problem, like Kevin pointed out you can't transfer connection ownership for odbc and other drivers like mysql/otp.

If you want to use a connection pool, take a look at this instead https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp-poolboy

Otherwise, you can use any pool but the process that executes the sql queries has to be the one that opened the connections.

---

### example in Erlang

```
sql_query_priv(Conn, Conn_Params, {SQL, Params}) ->
    lager:debug("~p:sql_query_priv trying to execute query: ~p, with params: ~p, conn = ~p~n", [?MODULE, SQL, Params, Conn]),
    case Conn of 
    null -> try mysql:start_link(Conn_Params) of
            {ok, NewConn} ->  
                  lager:info("~p:sql_query_priv Connection to DB Restored", [?MODULE]),
                  try mysql:query(NewConn, SQL, Params) of
                    ok ->  {ok, NewConn, []};
                    {ok, _Columns, Results} -> {ok, NewConn, Results};
                    {error, Reason} ->  
                        lager:error("~p:sql_query_priv Connection To DB Failed, Reason: ~p~n", [?MODULE, {error, Reason}]),
                       exit(NewConn, normal),
                       {error, null, Reason}                            
                  catch 
                    Exception:Reason -> 
                        lager:error("~p:sql_query_priv Connection To DB Failed, Exception:~p Reason: ~p~n", [?MODULE, Exception, Reason]),
                        {error, null, {Exception, Reason}} 
                  end;
            {error, Reason} ->  
                   lager:error("~p:sql_query_priv Connection To DB Failed, Reason: ~p~n", [?MODULE, {error, Reason}]),
                   {error, Conn, Reason}                            
            catch 
                Exception:Reason -> 
                    lager:error("~p:sql_query_priv Connection To DB Failed, Exception:~p Reason: ~p~n", [?MODULE, Exception, Reason]),
                    {error, Conn, {Exception, Reason}} 
            end;
    Conn -> try mysql:query(Conn, SQL, Params) of
                ok ->  {ok, Conn, []};
                {ok, _Columns, Results} -> {ok, Conn, Results};                      
                {error, Reason} ->  
                        try exit(Conn, normal) of
                         _Any -> ok
                        catch
                         _E:_R -> ok
                        end,
                      lager:error("~p:sql_query_priv Connection To DB Failed, Reason: ~p~n", [?MODULE, {error, Reason}]),
                      {error, null, Reason}                            
            catch 
                Exception:Reason -> 
                        try exit(Conn, normal) of
                         _Any -> ok
                        catch
                         _E:_R -> ok
                        end,
                      lager:error("~p:sql_query_priv Connection To DB Failed, Exception:~p Reason: ~p~n", [?MODULE, Exception, Reason]),
                      {error, null, {Exception, Reason}} 
            end
    end.
```

Comment: Thanks @Roman. I changed my implementation and my issue is fixed. See the edits above if your curious.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [relevant documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/odbc.html#connect-2), an `odbc` connection is private to the `Genserver` process that created the connection.

> Opens a connection to the database. The connection is associated with
>   the process that created it and can only be accessed through it. This
>   function may spawn new processes to handle the connection. These
>   processes will terminate if the process that created the connection
>   dies or if you call disconnect/1.

You can compare this to `ETS` tables that can be set to `private`, except that in the case of `ETS` tables you can make them `public`. This is not possible with `odbc` connections, as such you should move your code inside the `Genserver`